# How to concat two string array by escaping duplicates in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I am trying to write a function that will take two string array and concat them but will escape duplicate array. For instance, in below two arrays `cat` is common. So I need to take `cat` only one time

`input array1 = ["dog", "cat", "rat"]
input array2 = ["fat", "cat", "bat"]
output array = ["dog", "cat", "rat", "fat", "bat"]`

Any guidance/ solution with built-in function or without any built-in function will help. TIA

Comment: LINQ Union is what you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **[Union](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.union(v=vs.110).aspx)**

```
string[] output = array1.Union(array2).ToArray();
```

**[WORKING FIDDLE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dFM6XQ)**

Answer (score 2):

You can use Union or Distinct.

```
var output = array1.Union(array2).ToArray();
// or
var output = array1.Concat(array2).Distinct().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var array1 = new[] { "dog", "cat", "rat" };
var array2 = new[] { "fat", "cat", "bat"};
var output = array1.Union(array2).ToArray();
```